# How can we share app registration - applications between those two Azure Active Directory / Azure Accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We have 2 azure accounts one for dev and one for prod.
Both dev and prod have a different root account.

Is there any way so that we can share app registration - applications between those two accounts?

Comment: By root account you mean different Azure AD tenants. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Yes different Azure AD tenants

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way so that we can share app registration - applications
> between those two accounts?

An App Registration can't be shared across multiple Azure AD tenants as such.

However what you can do is create a Service Principal for this app registration in each Azure AD tenant. For this the application must be marked as `multi-tenant`.

If you created the App Registration using Azure Portal, then a Service Principal is automatically created in the home tenant.

In the other tenant, a Service Principal is created automatically whenever a user from that tenant has consented to its use.

You may find this link helpful in understanding more about App Registrations and Service Principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals.